# after set default value attribite can't re-assign it

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I'm trying to do so "Projectile motion" experiment.

in HTML

```
<div>
    <label for="angle">Angle</label>
    <input id="angle" name="angle" type="number" max="90" min="0" value=50 ></input>
    <label for="velocity">Velocity</label>
    <input id="velocity" name="velocity" type="number" value=150></input>
    <button id="launch">Launch</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

And in JS:

```
let v = document.getElementById("velocity").value;
let degreeAngle = document.getElementById("angle").value;
```

I can change the value of V and Angle in the input by this is no effect on the value. (always v is 150 and angle 50)

why ? and how can I change those values?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. If you assigned to the `value` property, you'd see that reflected in the UI.

Comment: `v` is a copy of the `value`. Modifying `v` does not affect the html elements.

Comment: Ok , so how to fix this ?!

Comment: you need to create a onClick function for your launch button and in that function read the angle and velocity values something like this: https://codepen.io/wyzix33/pen/rNzaaBg?editors=1111

Comment: Hi T.J i cant change the value of the angle and speed .. they always the same as value attr . I want to inter the value in the input so can change the ui

Comment: @AhmedM.Osman - Again: If you assign to `value`, it **will** change: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/hc528kad/ Do that in response to whatever it is that occurs (a user click, a timer event, whatever) that makes you want to change the value. Note that the `value` attribute on the element won't change (if you wanted to change it, you could write to the `defaultValue` property instead), but the value of hte input will change.

Comment: Do you want to change those values from JS code? or change them by hand and get the new values in JS variables?

Comment: change them by hand in the input @Gabriel

Comment: do you mean change the "value" to "defaultValue" 
I did this now its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a way to respond to changes in the values set by the user. What you're looking for is an event handler (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers).

Event handlers allow you to attach a callback function to an element and have it execute whenever some event occurs.

You can attach an event handler to the `click` event on the `#launch` button and run your calculations/simulation like so:

```js
function onLaunchClicked() {
  let v = document.getElementById("velocity").value;
  let degreeAngle = document.getElementById("angle").value;
  // Run simulation
}

let launchButton = document.getElementById("launch");
launchButton.addEventListener("click", onLaunchClicked);
```

Comment: I get launchButton.addEventHandler is not a function

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, the function is called `addEventListener`.